# How to configure route in htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, opencart2.3

I need to know how to configure the htaccess for when I access:

http://teste.com.br/route=feed/rest_api/count_products&key=123456

The action load most be:

http://teste.com.br/index.php?route=extension/feed/rest_api/count_products&key=123456

I need this to configuire an integration with another system.

- Remembering that I need something generic that works for all methods within rest_api

I tried this but not work:

```
RewriteRule ^route=feed/? index.php?route=extension/feed/$1  [L]
```

Comment: `http://teste.com.br/route=feed/rest_api/count_products&key=123456` is strange URL as there is no `?` but there is a `&`

Comment: I think that `http://teste.com.br/index.php?route=feed/rest_api/count_products&key=123456` will work too

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule as your **top rule**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(route)=(feed/[^&]*&key=\d+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?:index\.php)?$ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1=extension/%2 [L,NC]
```